# Installing Nvidia Graphics drivers on Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, lightdm, gdm, ubuntu-gnome

I am using Ubntu-GNOME 16.04 with *GNOME 3.20*

When I install Nvidia graphic drivers by `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361` , I am facing the following problems.

During the installation of Nvidia-361, it asks me to select **Default Display Manager** with the following options

- lightdm
- gdm3

### Consequences of selecting `lightdm`  :

The login screen becomes like this :

[image]

I don't want this screen. I want the **Default (nice) GNOME login screen**.

#### Furthermore....

When I enter my password and press enter, I get this screen for about 5 seconds :

[image]

### Consequences of selecting `gdm3`  :

Well I get **nothing!**

After rebooting, Ubuntu loads ... then all of a sudden my display turns of. **No Light**. I have waited enough but alas :( no change.

**NOTE:**

I have tried both `nvidia-361` in default repositories and `nvidia-361` from `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`. No difference.

I also tried installing `nvidia-364` and `nvidia-367` from graphics-drivers:ppa , alas :( no much difference.

### Using `nvidia-364` or `nvidia-367` :

When I tried these drivers, I could get GUI back. But I got stuck on the login page : **login loop**

Comment: What about `nvidia-364` from the graphics drivers PPA, or even `367`?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I have not tried them. thought they were beta

Comment: They might be, but if they work then what's the issue? :p

Comment: I have a maxwell nvidia card, and my display wouldn't work on 16.04 with anything older than 364 from the ppa (or nouveau, but the performance was awful).

Comment: What Nvidia graphics card is it? Does your Nvidia card have prime support?

Comment: @octoquad Nvidia G-force 820M . Yes it has prime support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most likely have hit this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1559576 which renders Nvidia prime cards currently unusable. You can maybe try some workarounds provided in the comments, but these might not work. However please do share your findings!

Comment: Yes. This is very much related.  Thanks for the link :-)

Comment: This bug was updated with a work-around: sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-legacy.  This seems to work for me; I am using 17.04 with nvidia-375, but the suggestion in the bug report is for 16.04.