# Failed to start after nvidia-driver install

Tags: nvidia, reboot, ubuntu-gnome

I just installed nvidia-driver via Software Manager in Ubuntu Gnome.
Now I have rebooted and this is the situation:
[image: monitor]
What's the best way to proceed? 
Uninstall nvidia-drivers via CLI?

Comment: You have rebooted and what happened? Please elaborate.

Comment: I had the [**same problem**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/778300/installing-nvidia-graphics-drivers-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04) , I switched back to Ubuntu vanilla. 
If you want to continue with GNOME, I would suggest you not to install any Nvidia drivers. Use it as it

Comment: @Melebius I'm sorry, photo wasn't uploaded!

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu GNOME :

If you find this bug affects you, please mark the same in this bug report :
**https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1559576** as given below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So that it may be able to boot your system:

```
 $ sudo apt remove nvidia-settings nvidia-prime nvidia-361
 $ sudo reboot
```

This is a known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1559576 which nowadays can't be solved.