# Nvidia GTX 950m driver problem

Tags: nvidia

Please help me,
I tried a lots of drivers for the graphic card, but the problem not solved :S 
In unity i have screen tearing, in Gnome, after when i switched to nvidia driver,, the gdm not load :S

Answer (score 1):

This was addressed in [Installing Nvidia Graphics drivers on Ubuntu-GNOME 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/780950).

> You most likely have hit this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1559576 which renders Nvidia prime cards currently unusable. You can maybe try some workarounds provided in the comments, but these might not work.